# Run both Docker and Virtualbox on Linux? Or Docker within VM?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, docker

Short version: I think I messed up wanting to run both Docker and Virtualbox on Linux at the same time and I'm thinking I should I migrate my docker setup into its own virtual machine?

```
System Summary (Linux Mint Host)
    Current OS: Linux Mint 21.1 Vera base: Ubuntu 22.04 jammy
    Desktop: Cinnamon 5.6.8
    Motherboard: ASRock B550M-ITX/ac
    CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 5500 (SVM Enabled)
    GPU: NVIDIA G96CGL [Quadro FX 580] (old, just using for now)
    SSD: 500GB with 2 partitions (Linux Mint partition and Alpine Linux Partition)

Network Devices:
    NAS: QNAP NAS w 40TB SMB Share (main storage). Runs a Plex server but don't want to run Containers on it due to limited RAM and CPU
    Main Desktop Running Windows 10 (used to VNC and SSH into 'server' to administer)
```

I put together this machine as a sort of 'home micro server', to learn and play with Docker to host some applications like Plex, build a web based monitoring dashboard for my systems and use it for basic admin tasks (renaming/sorting with Filebot, deduping with czkawka).

But I also wanted to use it to host some VMs so that I could use one as remote desktop for logging into when away (likely Linux Mint), and some others to install/play around with other distros and do some python scripting in a more contained environment.
The basics of my Docker environment are setup and running now, but when I went to start on the VMs I ran into some issues and errors;

```
VM Name: MintBox
VirtualBox can't enable the AMD-V extension. Please disable the KVM kernel extension, recompile your kernel and reboot (VERR_SVM_IN_USE).
Result Code:NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0X80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface:IConsole {6ac83d89-6ee7-4e33-8ae6-b257b2e81be8}
```

After a few hours of forum reading, I think I've realized that despite Docker and Virtualbox being different, they don't play well together and it looks like they both use the same SVM/Virtualization kernel/module/'thing'. At first I thought the conflict was due to x11vnc running on the Host, but digging in using `lsof | grep kvm`, it looks like Docker is the conflict. I did look at using Docker to run a full OS, but I think that might be more complicated and open to risk.

So before I get any further, should I stop and move the docker environment into it's own VM, so I can then leave it running and have other VMs alongside? What are my other low maintenance options?

First post/question and relatively new to Virtualization and Docker with a basic understanding of Linux so please be gentle.

Comment: Never heard of it (conflict whatsoever). Maybe in Windows, but not in Linux. Besides Docker (in the typical cases at least) isn't even virtualization. You don't even need any "hardware assistance" for it AFAIK (again this is talking about a Linux host).

Comment: I had never thought it would be an issue either. Never saw anything to suggest otherwise.
But when running `lsof | grep kvm`, a heap of `qemu-syst` processes come up that I assume are using the module and qemu was one of the requirements when installing Docker.
Unless I have installed it 'wrong' somehow... As mentioned, still new to this.

Comment: Uhm, unless you using/doing something like this? https://github.com/joshkunz/qemu-docker (Btw, perhaps you should just `pgrep -af qemu` to see if you can get more hints on what exactly the qemu VM is for.)

Comment: Ok... Haven't pulled or run the qemu-docker image or container at all.
However I'm now wondering if it's because I'm running Docker Desktop? Not just the Docker Engine? https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/linux-install/
Big orange box at the top has me thinking.

Remove Docker Desktop? Just run Docker Engine now that I'm up and running (and  have Portainer to manage containers)

Comment: Sounds to be the case. I suppose Docker Desktop does what you intended to try to resolve the problem, but then it's actually the cause of the problem. (I wasn't even aware that you can't run both qemu/kvm and vbox at the same time, to be frank. I thought it was only a Windows/Hyper-V thing)

Comment: Confirmed. Closed Docker Desktop and all is good in the world.
Had to export my Portainer data and then reload Portainer using `docker run`, but the containers I had are up and running (including Krusader which used a VNC interface) and I can now boot my VMs fine (both premade ones and empty ones for new install).
Note for others, Docker Desktop seems to be almost like a totally separate instance of Docker, not just an interface for the engine on Linux. My previously installed and configured containers and volumes weren't available using `docker container ls`

Answer (score 3):

Docker Desktop was the issue.

`pgrep -af qemu` showed reference to `file=/home/USER/.docker/desktop/vms/0/data/Docker.raw` and when looking at the documentation docs.docker.com/desktop/install/linux-install closer, Docker Desktop runs using the same VM/KVM/SVM that Virtualbox uses.

Closing Docker Desktop allowed me to run Virtualbox as intended, and I was able to re-launch my containers directly using the command line and `docker run`.

Note that Docker Desktop Containers, Volumes and Images sit separately to the standard Docker Engine so had to be re-launched without using desktop. Big thanks to Portainer for making this much more painless than it could have been!

Comment: I also suspected `virtualbox` conflicted with docker desktop aka `desktop-linux` because docker uses `kvm` and `kvm_intel`. That's a reason for `FATAL: Module kvm_intel is in use.` after `VirtualBox can't operate in VMX root mode. Please disable the KVM kernel extension, recompile your kernel and reboot (VERR_VMX_IN_VMX_ROOT_MODE)`.